# How can I check for particular value in firebase in a collection.document.collection.document() flutter dart

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I want to check if a certain id in a collection.document.collection.document() is available in firebase flutter dart, if it is so I remove the id else I add that id in the database.

So my problem is accessing the id value, I have tried .contains method but was always returning false even if the value is present. How can I work around this

this my firestore design

Firestore.instance
.collection('postt')
.document(postsId)
.collection('type')
.document();

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your firestore design look like but according to your description this example should work.

```
  DocumentSnapshot doc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posst')
    .doc('postsId')
    .collection('type')
    .where('id',isEqualTo: 'your id')
    .get();
  if(doc.exists){
      // todo 
  }else{
    // todo
  }
```

Comment: so, this checks if the document exists only. am a junior dev help me understand...... I want to check for a particular id in the document

Comment: @vinchuli I think I get your point you need where clause to get specific value in your document I edit my question hope It will help

Comment: this an eye opening ,had not thought in this line,. i give it a try